# nodebox grid() vs. grid library

Tags: python, nodebox

In Nodebox you can have:

1. grid() as a command
2. grid as a library

If I follow this tutorial:

http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Grid

It says to import grid with this:

grid = ximport("grid")

But in nodebox this is a command, which is why I believe things dont work as they should.

Is that correct?
If not how do I import that correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. When you import the grid library, `grid = ximport("grid")`, you can no longer use the built-in `grid` function. However, the functionality of the grid library is a superset of the `grid` built-in. That is, you can do everything and more with the library that you could with the function. The function is provided as a simple to use way of creating a grid, whereas the library provides more customization.

If you really feel like you need to use both, you can do as I suggested in [this NB forum thread](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/shared_2009-07-31-13-36-17) and rename the grid function before you import the library:

```
gridfunc = grid
grid = ximport("grid")
```